# How to make radio button works two task?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I made a form with two radio buttons, two textboxes and when one radio button is clicked one textbox is enable and the other one will be disable. But how to make radio button checked at the beginning before the radio button is clicked ?

Here is my code that will enable a textbox when radio button is clicked:

```
<input onclick="document.getElementById('agree_ad').disabled = false; document.getElementById('agree_bs').disabled = true;" type="radio" name="type1">

<input name="Agreement_ad" type="text" class="textField" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" id="agree_ad" />

<input onclick="document.getElementById('agree_ad').disabled = true; document.getElementById('agree_bs').disabled = false;" type="radio" name="type1" value="customurl1">

<input name="Agreement_bs" type="text" class="textField" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" id="agree_bs" />
```

What should I do to make first radio button clicked and textbox `id="agree_bs"` disable by default before click event is triggered.

Comment: They are `radio` buttons not `checkboxes`

Answer (score 1):

Apply the HTML attributes `checked` and `disabled` accordingly within your markup:

```html
<input type="radio" name="foo" checked />    <!-- this is checked -->
<input type="radio" name="foo" />            <!-- this isn't checked -->

<br>

<input type="text" disabled />    <!-- this is disabled -->
<input type="text" />             <!-- this isn't disabled -->
```

Comment: thnks a lot, i forgot to use disabled. I tried only by using checked

Answer (score 1):

You do not need fancy JavaScript to do this: simply add `checked` to the radio button and `disabled` to the second text box:

```
<input checked onclick="document.getElementById('agree_ad').disabled = false; document.getElementById('agree_bs').disabled = true;" type="radio" name="type1">

<input name="Agreement_ad" type="text" class="textField" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" id="agree_ad" />

<input onclick="document.getElementById('agree_ad').disabled = true; document.getElementById('agree_bs').disabled = false;" type="radio" name="type1" value="customurl1">

<input disabled name="Agreement_bs" type="text" class="textField" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" id="agree_bs" />
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh0ryz6s/)